# What is the significance of the title "You Should Have Seen the Mess" by Muriel Spark?

Tags: short-stories, title, muriel-spark

What is the significance of the title of Muriel Spark's short story "You Should Have Seen the Mess"?

Comment: This question would be more attractive if you gave an indication of what you know, or of what you suspect, or of why you ask the question, and how you have tried to answer the question up to now, and so on.  Do, for example, the words "you should have seen the mess" appear in the story anywhere?  As it stands, your question looks like  an appeal for others to do your school work for you.